# dplyr::cume_dist() has different results on similar data, is this a bug?

Tags: r, dplyr

Similar data gives different results with the functions cume_dist() (and also percent_rank()) in dplyr.

[Edit: thanks for the comments. Much simpler demonstration of the problem:]

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = runif(5), b = runif(5))
df[5, ] <- NA
df <- mutate(df, x = cume_dist(a - b), y = a - b)
out <- mutate(df, z = cume_dist(y))
```

yields:

```
> out
# A tibble: 5 x 5
       a       b     x       y     z
   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.154  0.427   0.25  -0.273   0.2
2  0.880  0.0455  0.75   0.835   0.6
3  0.989  0.0208  1      0.968   0.8
4  0.901  0.303   0.5    0.598   0.4
5 NA     NA      NA     NA      NA
```

Why would columns `x` and `z` be different? Isn't this a bug?

[Edit #2: For posterity, here is a better demonstration. Columns `indirect` and `direct` should not be different.]

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)
df <- tibble(a = runif(1000, -1, 1), b = runif(1000, -1, 1))
df[df < 0] <- NA_real_  # or NA, doesn't matter
df <- df %>%
  mutate(gain = b - a)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(indirect = cume_dist(gain), 
         direct = cume_dist(b - a))
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.5
```

with versions:

```
dplyr_0.8.1       
tidyverse_1.2.1
```

Comment: Are `df` and `new_df` really similar ? I don't think so

Comment: The rank of `df$y` and `new_df$gain` is similar, I mean. The result of `all(rank(df$y) == rank(new_df$gain))` is true.

Comment: Thanks, ANG, new testcase provided.

Comment: It is better to use `set.seed` if you are creating an example with `runif`

Comment: I think it is NA dispatch issue, please check my update.  If you assign the correcct NA, ie. `df[5, ] <- NA_real_` should work

Comment: Thanks @akrun for getting into the weeds on this issue. Unfortunately changing the NA to NA_real_ in my 5-line testcase doesn't change the result. Is this a bug? Why this matters: my first plot of an empirical density using cume_dist() topped at 0.987 instead of 1 (using the examples of `nycflights13` in Chapter 5 of R for Data Science) because 13 of 970 March 20 flights had missing data for `gain = dep_delay - arr_delay`.

Comment: @ceelanks I am able to get the expected output based on the first input example.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned earlier, if you use `cume_dist` outside the `mutate`, it should work fine.  Anyway, it looks like I have spent too much time on this without much benefit for me

Comment: I am not getting any issue with replacing `out[5, ] <- NA_real_;  out %>% mutate(new = cume_dist(y)) %>% select(x, new)## A tibble: 5 x 2
      x   new
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.5   0.5 
2  0.75  0.75
3  1     1   
4  0.25  0.25
5 NA    NA`  It is the same

Answer (score 0):

It would be the issue with correct `NA` dispatch.  Here, the `NA` was created by assigning just `NA`.  and by default it would be `NA_logical_`.  Some reason, the `cume_dist` inside the `mutate` is not recognising.  An option is to `round` or use `as.integer` so that the `NA` gets converted to correct `NA`

```
new_df %>% 
  mutate(gain = round(gain), cume_dist = cume_dist(gain))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#   gain cume_dist
#  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     0       0.6
#2    30       0.8
#3    36       1  
#4   -13       0.2
#5     0       0.6
#6    NA      NA
```

Or convert to `integer`

```
new_df %>% 
   mutate(gain = as.integer(gain), cume_dist = cume_dist(gain))
```

---

The issue would be that the `NA` is not recognized within the `mutate`.  If we check the function, `cume_dist`

```
cume_dist
#function (x) 
#{
#    rank(x, ties.method = "max", na.last = "keep")/sum(!is.na(x))
#}
```

It is taking the `rank` and divide by the number of non-NA elements in that column.  By doing the same code

```
new_df %>% 
     mutate(Cume_dist = rank(gain, ties.method = "max", 
            na.last = "keep")/sum(!is.na(gain)))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#   gain Cume_dist
#  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     0       0.6
#2    30       0.8
#3    36       1  
#4   -13       0.2
#5     0       0.6
#6    NA       NA
```

If we change the denominator by the number of rows of dataset

```
new_df %>% 
          mutate(Cume_dist = rank(gain, ties.method = "max", na.last = "keep")/n())
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#   gain Cume_dist
#  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     0     0.5  
#2    30     0.667
#3    36     0.833
#4   -13     0.167
#5     0     0.5  
#6    NA    NA
```

It means within the `mutate` env, there is some changes going on with the `NA` element, taking the `n()` instead of 5 in denominator

Note that it is not an issue outside the `mutate`

```
cume_dist(new_df$gain)
#[1] 0.6 0.8 1.0 0.2 0.6  NA
```

Now, if we change the `NA` to `NA_real_` (the column is double and the OP had assigned `NA` without any suffix.  So, it would be `NA_logical_` by default.  Usually, it should work, but `cume_dist` may have some bug to correctly identifying it inside the `mutate`).  Let's try changing the `NA` to `NA_real_`

```
new_df$gain[is.na(new_df$gain)] <- NA_real_
new_df %>%
   mutate(Cume_dist = cume_dist(gain))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#   gain Cume_dist
#  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     0       0.6
#2    30       0.8
#3    36       1  
#4   -13       0.2
#5     0       0.6
#6    NA      NA
```

#### data

```
df <- tibble(y = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 2, NA))
out1 <- mutate(df, 
  min_rank = min_rank(y),
  pct_rank = percent_rank(y),
  cume_dist = cume_dist(y)
)
flights_sml <- filter(flights, month == 3, day == 20)
r1 <- min(which(is.na(flights_sml$dep_delay)))
new_df <- flights_sml[c(9, (r1-4):r1), ]
new_df <- mutate(new_df,
  gain = dep_delay - arr_delay)
new_df <- select(new_df, gain)
```

Comment: I agree that `round(gain)` and `as.integer(gain)` cause `out1` and `out2` to agree, but I think the ranking should be the same regardless. In the provided example, `all(rank(df$y) == rank(new_df$gain))` is true, so why would the `dplyr::cume_dist()` behavior differ? Thanks for checking into this question.

Comment: @ceelanks I updated with some more info.  In case you are okay with my efforsts

Comment: I made a simpler testcase to demonstrate what I perceive as a bug. I was hoping that `x` and `z` would be the same in the implementation. If it should be different, I have to know why so I can avoid coding problems in the future. Long-time R user, first-time dplyr learner, so thanks for your patience! :-)

Comment: I agree that changing `NA` to `NA_real_` in this `nycflights13` testcase fixes the problem. Unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem in my simplified testcase in the original post. Thanks!

Comment: @ceelanks  Have you tried `cume_dist(new_df$gain)` outside the `mutate`

Comment: Yes, `cume_dist()` outside `dplyr::mutate` works fine. This seems like a bug and I'll submit a bug report through R. Thanks for you work on this question!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. See [#4427](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commit/dfcdc660eed0187bf8e175afd530ad49503e9da6) for `dplyr` 0.8.2 milestone.